# Using the distinct function in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, distinct

This may sound like a strange question but I am trying to use the distinct clause in order to get all the names in a database however I want the first name to be unique

**Table structure**

```
id   fname   lname   haircolor
1    john    doe     brown
2    bob     seagal  blonde
3    kevin   smith   red
4    bob     doe     green
```

**Desired output**

```
john doe brown
bob seagal blonde
kevin smith red
```

I have tried

```
SELECT fname, lname, haircolor
FROM MainTable
INNER JOIN (select distinct frame from MainTable) as Names
ON MainTable.fname=Names.fname
```

This has not worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are selecting `frame` instead of `fname` from MainTable. Does it work when you fix that typo?

Comment: I assume that `frame` and `fname` is a typo… Could you elaborate on *it doesn't work*.

Comment: Do you want the first name unique across all rows?  Or do you want an arbitrary value for the first name?

Comment: @ Eric Petroelje : I deleted my answer and only afterwards read your comment on the deleted node, you where right that's why I deleted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `GROUP BY` instead:

```
SELECT fname, lname, haircolor
FROM yourtable
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT MIN(id) FROM yourtable GROUP BY fname
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! What does "IN" do?

Comment: @user939951 `a IN (SELECT col FROM ...)` returns true if the select clause returns a row containing the value a.

Comment: Check whether a value is within a set of values  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Comment: `Select * From Names Where fname in ('Bob', 'Jim')` would give you all records with Bob or Jim as the fname.  Here Mark is using a subquery to determine the first id for each unique name, and then the outer query selects all records matching those id's.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
SELECT fname, lname, haircolor FROM MainTable GROUP BY fname
```

Comment: [GROUP BY and HAVING with Hidden Columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html): "The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate." So it's not guaranteed to work, but it probably will.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT fname,SUBSTRING_INDEX( MAX(CONCAT(lname,'~',haircolor)) , '~', 1 ) lname
 ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( MAX(CONCAT(lname,'~',haircolor)) , '~', 2 ),'~',-1) haircolor from MainTable
```